# multiple http get calls nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, request, node-async

Thanks for looking into the code.

Here I am fetching some data using feed parser and taking out id's in navcodes array variable and wants to use these Id to make http call.Please find code below.

```
function processNavCode(){
    var mfId = [53];
    var preTitle = '';
    var navCodes = [];
    mfId.forEach(function(id){
        var query = "http://portal.xyz.com/Rss.aspx?mf="+id;
        feed(query, function(err, feeds) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            feeds.forEach(function(feed){
                var link = feed.link;
                var title = feed.title;
                var navCode = link.substr(link.length - 6);
                if(title.split('-')[0].trim() != preTitle){
                    preTitle = title;
                    counter ++;
                }
                if(parseInt(navCode) != '')
                    navCodes.push = parseInt(navCode);
            });
        });
        async.eachSeries(navCodes,insertbulkMFValues,function(){
            console.log('I am done');
        });

// insertbulkMFValues(navCode);
//Directly call insertbulkMFValues  function
    });
}
```

I have also tried to call the insertbulkMFValues  directly as commented now but due to async nature of nodejs, I am getting the error of either 'Socket hang up' or 'read ECONNRESET'. I checked and used async but not able to work with that also.

```
var insertbulkMFValues  =function(navCode,callback){
    var options = {
        host: 'www.quandl.com',
        path: '/api/v3/datasets/AMFI/'+navCode+'.json?api_key=123456789&start_date=2013-08-30',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    var req1 = https.request(options, function(response) {
        var body = '';
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            if(typeof body === "string") {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
            }
            var mfData = json.dataset.data;
            var schemeId = json.dataset.dataset_code;
            var schemeName = json.dataset.name;
            var isinCode = json.dataset.description;
            var valueData=[];
            for (var k = 0; k < mfData.length; k++) {
                var myDate = new Date(mfData[k][0]);
                valueData.push({
                    date:myDate,
                    NAV:parseFloat(mfData[k][1]).toFixed(2)
                }); 
            }
            var query = { "navCode": schemeId };
            var newData = { 
                createdDate: Date.now(),
                navCode: schemeId,
                schemeCode:count,
                schemeName:schemeName,
                ISINCode:isinCode,
                values:valueData
            };
            MHistory.findOneAndUpdate(query, newData , {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
            if(err)
                console.log('Errorr');
            else
                console.log('Success');
        });    
    });
});
    req1.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        callback(true);
    });
    req1.end();
}
```

Thanks in advance..
J

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call `insertbulkMFValues` for each navCode like:

```
if(parseInt(navCode) != '') {
     insertbulkMFValues(navCode, function () {
        console.log('something'} 
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that you intend to do must be within the callback of the asynchronous function.
One option for you is to use the waterfall or parallel method of the async library to retrieve all feeds for each id and then invoke

```
    async.eachSeries(navCodesAccumulated,insertbulkMFValues,function(){
        console.log('I am done');
    });
```

within the final result callback using the codes obtained.